# Text does not get appended to file

Tags: php

The text file seems to be overwritten whenever I try appending more text to it. Here's the code:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://optifine.net/');
$txt = "data.txt";
$fh = fopen($txt, 'w+');
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both fields are set
   $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'];
   file_put_contents('data.txt',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND); // log to data.txt
   exit();
}
    fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the user running php has permission to write to that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP says "text file seems to be overwritten" means contents are written to file, so this is not an issue related to permissions.

try opening your file with

```
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a+');
```

instead of your line saying;

```
$fh = fopen($txt, 'w+');
```

Refer to PHP Documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Explanations about mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per **[`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)**, you only need

```
file_put_contents('data.txt',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

Contents are getting appended using `file_put_contents` are getting overwritten by `fopen`. You should use either of them, not both.

Moreover, you are using `fopen` with `w+`, which actually truncate the file

> Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning
>   of the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows how to **not** write code. It mixes [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)/[`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)/[`fclose()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). It cannot make its mind about the purpose of variable `$txt`; it is a file name in the beginning then it is some content to write to the file. It opens a file then forgets about it; in the `if` block the script exits without caring about the open file.

There is no reason to mix `file_put_contents()` with `fwrite()` and its friends.

It's easier with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
header('Location: http://optifine.net/');
$filename = 'data.txt';

if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
   $text = $_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'];
   file_put_contents($filename, $text, FILE_APPEND);
   exit();
}
```

Behind the scene, [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) opens the file ([`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)), writes the data into it ([`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)) then closes it ([`fclose()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)). Let's try to do the same:

```
header('Location: http://optifine.net/');
$filename = 'data.txt';

if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
   $text = $_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'];

   // Do what file_put_contents($filename, $text, FILE_APPEND) does
   $fh = fopen($filename, 'a');
   if ($fh) {
       fwrite($fh, $text);
       fclose($fh);
   }
   exit();
}
```